# JSF filterBy stalls and everything else in the page gets blocked

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a dataTable and in a column a filterBy parameter.

When I type something on the filter box, it indeed filters the table but when I delete or change what I wrote on that field nothing happens and every other action in the page is blocked.

I mean, after that if I click on a button nothing happens, no event-action is performed.

I'm using JSF 2.1, on Tomcat 7, with EE5.

What are your suggestions? Thanks a lot in advance.

XHTML code fragment:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{consolidacionAslBean.listaMunicipios}"
    rowKey="#{municipio}" var="municipio" paginator="true"
    rows="5" id="tableMunicipio"
    selection="#{consolidacionAslBean.municipios}" style="font-size: 13px"
    filteredValue="#{consolidacionAslBean.filteredMunicipios}"
    >

<p:column 
        filterBy="#{municipio.catMunicipios.id.cdgMunicipio}"  
        headerText="Clave">
    <h:outputText value="#{municipio.catMunicipios.id.cdgMunicipio}" />
</p:column>
```

And bean the proper objects:

```
private List<AslMunicipios> filteredMunicipios;
private List<AslMunicipios> listaMunicipios;
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would be better if you post a code snippet in form of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks, I've edited my question with the proper code snippet.